# Delete Realm objects during the migration

Tags: java, android, realm, database-migration

I want to delete the entries of a specific table during the migration (old objects will not be relevant anymore).

How do I do it properly? Can I just call `delete()` or do I need to call `beginTransaction()` and `endTransaction()` too?

```
@Override
public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
    RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

    if(oldVersion < 4) {
        // do the migration here
        realm.delete("ChartObject"); // is this correct for deleting all ChartObjects?
        oldVersion = 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Yes, you are correct](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/DynamicRealm.html#delete-java.lang.String-). Migration already runs as a write transaction, so don't begin/end.